# Correct way to align text

Tags: javascript, html, css, containers, alignment

I'm tryin to recreate this photo below and I am so close. I have run into a problem and I cannot seem to fix it. **In my Snippet the text is not vertical aligned with the other container divs like they are in the photo. How can I align my text so the words are aligned?** I have tried using flex box but because some text are longer/shorter then others they are all out of alignment because their positions are fixed.
[image]

```js
const storeItems = [
    {
        name: 'TV',
        price: 800.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: '4K Ultra HD'
    },
    {
        name: 'Phone',
        price: 700.00,
        inStock: false,
        details: '5G'
    },
    {
        name: 'Game Console',
        price: 300.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: 'The latest and greatest'
    },
    {
        name: 'Laptop',
        price: 1200.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: '16GB RAM 1TB SSD'
    },
    {
        name: 'Smart Watch',
        price: 200.00,
        inStock: false,
        details: 'Counts your steps'
    },
    {
        name: 'Headphones',
        price: 100.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: 'Clearest music to be heard'
    },
    {
        name: 'Keyboard',
        price: 100.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: 'Types for you'
    },
    {
        name: 'HDMI Cord',
        price: 100.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: 'HDMI to USB type C'
    },
    {
        name: 'Monitor',
        price: 300.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: '4K Ultra HD'
    },
    {
        name: 'Speaker',
        price: 200.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: 'Clearest music to be heard'
    },
    {
        name: 'Video Game',
        price: 60.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: 'Enjoy for hours'
    },
];

storeItems.forEach(function(n, i, a) {
  if (n.inStock == true) {
   $('.boxes').append('<div class="container">' + '<p>$' + n.price +'</p>' + '<p>' + n.name + '</p>' + '<p>' + n.details + '</p>'
   + 
  '</div>');
  }
 if (n.inStock == false) {
  $('.boxes').append('<p class="notInStock">' + n.name + ': $' + 
  n.price + ' Not in stock' + '</p>');
  }
  
})

$('#clickMe').appendTo('.boxes');



$('#clickMe').click(function(){
    $('#contentContainer').toggleClass('darkModeBackground');
    $('.container').toggleClass('darkModeContainers');
    $(this).toggleClass('darkModeClickMe');
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: black;
}

.shrink-container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#clickMe {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#clickMe:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.inStock{
    
}

.notInStock{
    display:none;
}

.darkModeBackground{
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
}
.darkModeContainers{
    background-color: #5A5A5A;
    color: white;
}
.darkModeClickMe{
    border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>List of items</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body id="contentContainer">
  <div class="shrink-container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <p>______
        <p>
    </div>
    <div id="appendToMe">
      <div class="boxes">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="clickMe">Toggle Dark Mode</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-MlusDLJIP1GRgLrOflUQtshyP0TwT/RHXsI1wWGnQhs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a table? That seems like the ideal structure to display data like that.

Comment: Yes, flexbox is not the right solution for this problem. I would use either a table or a grid.

Comment: I tried swapping it over but the result looks very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `<table>`.

```js
const storeItems = [
    {
        name: 'TV',
        price: 800.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: '4K Ultra HD'
    },
    {
        name: 'Phone',
        price: 700.00,
        inStock: false,
        details: '5G'
    },
    {
        name: 'Game Console',
        price: 300.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: 'The latest and greatest'
    },
    {
        name: 'Laptop',
        price: 1200.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: '16GB RAM 1TB SSD'
    },
    {
        name: 'Smart Watch',
        price: 200.00,
        inStock: false,
        details: 'Counts your steps'
    },
    {
        name: 'Headphones',
        price: 100.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: 'Clearest music to be heard'
    },
    {
        name: 'Keyboard',
        price: 100.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: 'Types for you'
    },
    {
        name: 'HDMI Cord',
        price: 100.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: 'HDMI to USB type C'
    },
    {
        name: 'Monitor',
        price: 300.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: '4K Ultra HD'
    },
    {
        name: 'Speaker',
        price: 200.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: 'Clearest music to be heard'
    },
    {
        name: 'Video Game',
        price: 60.00,
        inStock: true,
        details: 'Enjoy for hours'
    },
];

storeItems.forEach(function(n, i, a) {
  $('#appendToMe').append('<tr><td>$' + n.price +'</td><td>' + n.name + '</td><td>' + n.details + '</td></tr>');
})

$('#clickMe').click(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('darkModeBackground');
    $('#appendToMe').toggleClass('dark');
    $(this).toggleClass('darkModeClickMe');
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: black;
}

#appendToMe {
  border-spacing: 0 .5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

tr {
  background-color: white;
}

td {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

td:first-child {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#clickMe button {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.darkModeBackground {
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
}
#appendToMe.dark tr {
    background-color: #5A5A5A;
    color: white;
}
.darkModeClickMe {
    border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <table id="appendToMe"></table>
  <div id="clickMe"><button>Toggle Dark Mode</button></div>
</body>
```